# Module not found (Swiperjs in Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I want use swiperjs but
I am getting a module not found error.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIph5.png)

Comment: Which version of swiper you are using ?, show me the package.json

Comment: I use "swiper": "^7.0.4".(I add to img on post)

Comment: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper/issues/570. and try the methods mentioned in the link. also check the last comment.

Comment: import 'swiper/css/bundle' try this instead

Comment: It didn't work. When I do "npm install --save swiper/dist/css/swiper.css" I faced the this problem "A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\tarik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-10T08_16_02_881Z-debug.log"

Comment: No you cant do this -  npm install --save swiper/dist/css/swiper.css.    
just "npm install --save  swiper " is enough. no need to install CSS separately

Comment: I did what you said (just npm install --save swiper) but it didn't work

Comment: Hi! Please post your code as formatted text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'
```

instead of import 'swiper/css'

I had a similar issue in my vue procet and the problem was that apps created by create-vue-app apparently don't support pure JS modules like swiper. You can read more about that here https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871 and the referenced solution https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

You imported wrong ccs file. You should change

```
import './style.css'
```

Comment: He is trying to import CSS files from the swiper package, not his local directory CSS file